# Data being send through android app and show on webpage

Tags: javascript, php, android, json, web-services

I have an android app that sends data through HttpRequest using JSON format, that data is being received through php webpage, problem is I want to show all the data that is being transmitted through my app on webpage, perhaps in a table...I can insert into the MySQL db but data is being received very fast, and at this instant I just want to show on webpage, which keeps on changing when new data is received...
Hope you all can understand what I mean...
Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use a simple file for storage?

Comment: you can debug the process to know what data you send to your server

Comment: I just want to show that data live on server, may be will have to draw graph later, I don't want to save in file and then again retrieve as this will makes process slow

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you mean, you can use websocket, to display changing in realtime.